# How to make a call from GSM modem to other phone with PHP?

Tags: php, gsm, modem

I really want to know how to make a call by using GSM modem and PHP to other phone?
Please help me.
I am using PHP I can send SMS from GSM modem to other phone with php by using php serial extension but I cannot make a call.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: Maybe http://microcontrollerslab.com/how-to-make-call-using-gsm-module-on-mobile-phone/ will help